# Custom Image Size in Insert Media

Tags: functions, images

I have some custom image sizes set in my functions and it works just as one would expect, but I am would like this custom image size to be present when a user adds images to a post.

You know when you add an image to a post, in the bottom area it gives you the option to choose from predefined sizes; basically I would like to add my own size to this area...is that possible?

Comment: [see some examples here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=image_size_names_choose).

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this:

```
add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'jss_custom_image_sizes' );
function jss_custom_image_sizes( $sizes ){
    $custom_sizes = array(
        'customsize1'        =>        'Post Rectangle Image',
        'customsize2'        =>        'Post Square Image',
    );
    return array_merge( $sizes, $custom_sizes );
}
```